# Batch 7zip all files separately in a directory (Centos 7.6)

Tags: shell-script, centos, zip, 7z

I am trying to 7zip all files inside a directory separately into their own archive (for each file) in Linux Centos 7.6. Been looking around for a while but never found a method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'd like to do this to all regular files recursively in and below some top-level directory `$topdir`:

```
find "$topdir" -type f -exec 7za a {} {} \;
```

For a single directory containing *only* files that you'd like to compress, you would use

```
for pathname in "$topdir"/*; do
    7za a "$pathname" "$pathname"
done
```

The difference here is that hidden files would not be compressed.  If you enable the `dotglob` shell option in `bash` with `shopt -s dotglob`, then the loop would include hidden names.

With `find` (which would amount to less typing), you could do the files in a single directory with

```
find "$topdir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec 7za a {} {} \;
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. Let's say the top directory's name was Test. How would I make this work? I'm not that proficient in writing scripts.

Comment: I'd just modify the `{} {}` to `{}.7z {}` so something like `image.png` would archive to `image.png.7z`, otherwise 7zip threw error. And to also answer comment above, I've used full path such as: `find "/home/myuser/test/batch" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec 7za a {}.7z {} \;`